iRedMail and IpTables - mail not coming through and no errors. How to fix it?
Hello and happy upcoming NYE!
Trying to firewall iRedMail installation. Need to keep open only the ports necessary for incoming connections. Currently the rules are:
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:submission
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:submissions
ACCEPT     all  --  localhost            anywhere  
ACCEPT     all  --  185.121.228.0/24     anywhere

      

The last rule is to keep own SSH connection alive.
Currently no mail coming in and out, no errors and no bounced emails. Suspecting this may have something to do with SSL certificates used for SMTP not resolving hostnames, but I have enabled port 53 "domain" for it and it's not helping.
Stuck here. As soon as default policy changed from DROP to ACCEPT, it works like a breeze.
Any ideas on how to firewall iRedMail server properly are very appreciated!
Edit: SMTP (port 25) enabled for the sake of it, which is not being used anyway. Made no effect
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:submission
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:submissions
ACCEPT     all  --  localhost            anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  185.121.228.0/24     anywhere    

    


You don't allow SMTP.

port 25 isn't used, is it? I have enabled it now and nothing changed.

Port 25 is used. And you don't tell us what fails, or what you've done to verify firewall rules.


Port 25 is needed. E-mail is transported between servers via SMTP, which uses port 25.
Verify that a local service is listening on port 25, using e.g. lsof, netcat or similar.
Add logging so you can actually see what's going on.
Review logs for activity.
Make connection attempt externally and note failure message using e.g. netcat.
If external connections work, attempt e-mail delivery either manually using netcat or some other way which gives you access to delivery logs.

In addition, is there any reason for not using e.g. ufw as a frontend for iptables?
